# Using a loop in GEE to produce multiple maps

Tags: google-earth-engine

I have a functional GEE working script below. However, I want to map the fire incidences on a monthly basis from 2001 to 2020. I want to use loops to automate the process because doing it manually is taking a very long time. For example, I need to map fire incidences from January to December (monthly) between the years 2001 - 2020. So for January I would need one map for each year from 2001 to 2020. Then february one map for each year from 2001 to 2020 etc.

```
var zimbabwe = ee.FeatureCollection('users/amazhindu/zimbabwe')

Map.centerObject(zimbabwe, 7);

// Visualize FireCCI51 for the year 2001
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('ESA/CCI/FireCCI/5_1')
                  .filterDate('2001-12-01', '2001-12-31')
                  .filterBounds(zimbabwe)
                  .map(function(image){return image.clip(zimbabwe)});

// make a function to mask images based on the ConfidenceLevel band                  
var filterConfidence = function(image){
  var mask = image.select('ConfidenceLevel').gt(70);
  return image.updateMask(mask);
};

// map over the image collection and apply the mask
var confidentDataset = dataset.map(filterConfidence);

// original pixels
var burnedArea = dataset.select('BurnDate');

// pixels with confidence > 70
var burnedArea_Confidence_70 = confidentDataset.select('BurnDate').mean();

// visualise image collections for comparison
Map.addLayer(burnedArea, {palette:['0000ff']}, 'burned area');
Map.addLayer(burnedArea_Confidence_70, {palette:['ff0000']}, 'burned area confidence >70');

// add region of interest as a transparent polygon
Map.addLayer(zimbabwe.style({fillColor:'00000000'}), null, 'Zimbabwe');

Export.image.toDrive({
  image: burnedArea_Confidence_70,
  description: 'Burn_70_Zimbabwe_2001_december',
  //scale: 30,
  region: zimbabwe,
  fileFormat: 'GeoTIFF',
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can put your code inside a function and parameterize the year and month. Then invoke that function in a client-side loop:

```
for (var year = 2001; year <= 2020; year++)
  for (var month = 1; month <= 12; month++)
    fire(year, month)
    

function fire(year, month) {
  var startDate = ee.Date.fromYMD(year, month, 1)
  var endDate = startDate.advance(1, 'month')
  ...
}
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/52f2920b0649ffd5d52a6367fd85815e

You'll of course get some 120 export tasks that you still have to trigger manually. I suppose you could try to combine these images into a single 120 band image to export. You'll have to see if EE manages without running out of memory. Alternatively, you could export 10 yearly 12 band images, to keep it a little bit more manageable.

Comment: Just an FYI, pending tasks can be triggered by deffining and running two javascript functions,, the manual part can be mostly skipped.